# Can I Load posts from an External database if the post is not found on Main Wordpress Database

Tags: database, optimization

I have a WordPress Site on a dedicated server (on a considerably larger Capacity Server - 128GB RAM/64 Processor - 2TB NVme).

**THE PROBLEM**

We have a considerably large amount of data inside the database currently about 25GB and it's ever-growing, and based on the design of WordPress, I don't think it can handle a large amount of data and processing concurrent data based on the query structure ( I stand corrected). Because of this, our web app tends to load slowly and is sometimes inaccessible at peak traffic periods.

We have thought of and made research on so many possible solutions, but we have a budget constraint ( though I will still appreciate more possible solutions to the problem).

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION / SCENARIO We are Looking into**

We are looking at archiving old data from past years, which are not too relevant but still necessary for us to keep, thereby cutting down the total size of the database, but in this case, we want a situation where we/users can still access the data.

So I want to create a Secondary database (could be on-premise or external) which will contain the archived data

**THE QUESTION**

Can I load posts or redirect user traffic to the archived data on this external Secondary database if the post is not found in the Primary WordPress database ( which we have shrunk to reduce size)?

Comment: doing this will make your site slower not faster, as the query still needs to run so you're still paying the cost, only now you're adding in a tonne of additional code that wasn't there before to do something that is extremely fragile and non-standard. If your queries are slow and don't scale then you should focus on fixing that and asking about that, especially since there are sites that are far larger than what you've described that run just fine at a scale of billions of page views per day

Comment: ** If your queries are slow and don't scale then you should focus on fixing that and asking about that ** -- You mention this, How do I go about that? Any pointer, please?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes you can", but as Tom points out, your reasoning for this is faulty. Please research on identifying slow downs on your site, and then if you require community assistance, please post as a separate question.

Comment: you should identify slow queries and ask about them, but this isn't the place to do that, comments are for asking clarifying questions about the original question, if you have a _new_ question you should click the ask question button in the corner, but make sure it's specific enough it can be fully answered with facts not just recommendations/tips as this isn't a discussion forum. "How do I fix slow queries" won't be specific enough, you'll need examples